# Tensor Product: Denseness

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, tensor-products

*This is thread is just a note.*

Given Hilbert spaces.

Then denseness will be inherited on tensor products:
$$\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E}\text{ dense}\implies\mathcal{D}\otimes\mathcal{E}\text{ dense}$$

How to prove this from scratch without orthonormal bases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki.*

First for simple tensors one has:
$$\|\varphi\otimes\psi-\varphi_n\otimes\psi_n\|\leq\|\varphi-\varphi_n\|\cdot\|\psi\|+\|\varphi_n\|\cdot\|\psi-\psi_n\|\leq\delta_\varphi(1+\|\psi\|)+\|\varphi\|\delta_\psi$$
Next for sums it still holds true by continuity of addition:
$$\|\varphi\otimes\psi+\varphi'\otimes\psi'\|\leq\|\varphi\otimes\psi\|+\|\varphi'\otimes\psi'\|$$
Finally the result follows as sums are dense in the Hilbert tensor product.